# How to select one tkinter button at a time

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want my tkinter button to raised when selected before content in the entry can be printed but both button can be selected to be raised at the same time.All the behaviour i want my widget to act is performing only that am able to select both button at the same time which i want one to raised at a time.

```
import tkinter as tk


def output():

    global choosed

    if choosed:
        now = new.get()
        print(now)
    else:
        print("select predict button to proceed")


def raised_button(button_object):

    global choosed
    choosed = True

    button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)


def stop():

    global choosed
    choosed = False

    lot1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)
    lot2.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


new = tk.StringVar()
en = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=new).pack()

choosed = False


lot1 = tk.Button(root, text="GOOD")
lot1.configure(command=lambda button_object=lot1: 
raised_button(button_object))
lot1.pack(side="left")


lot2 = tk.Button(root, text="BAD")
lot2.configure(command=lambda button_object=lot2: 
raised_button(button_object))
lot2.pack()


tk.Button(root, text="print number", command=lambda :[output(),
stop()]).place(x=150, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

if button `GOOD` is selected the sunken is applied to it only then if select button `BAD` sunken effect is applied to it the button `Good` sunken effect is disabled.

Comment: i want only one button to be selected but with the code above i can select both button

Comment: tkinter raised effect should be applied to one button not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand only one button can be sunken. If you click second button then first button (which is sunken) have to raise again.

You can use `stop()` inside `raise_button()`.

```
def raised_button(button_object):
    global choosed
    choosed = True

    stop()

    button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)
```

Or you can use `choosed` to remember suken button and raise it when you click other button.

```
def raised_button(button_object):
    global choosed

    if choosed: # previously clicked
        choosed.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)

    choosed = button_object
    button_object.configure(relief=tk.SUNKEN, state=tk.DISABLED)

def stop():
    global choosed

    choosed = None

    lot1.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)
    lot2.configure(relief=tk.RAISED, state=tk.ACTIVE)

#----

choosed = None # set at start
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use `Radiobuttons` with `indicatoron=0` and they will look like normal buttons but still only one `Radiobutton` can be selected.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

v = tk.IntVar()

tk.Radiobutton(root, text="One", variable=v, value=1, indicatoron=0).pack()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Two", variable=v, value=2, indicatoron=0).pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=lambda:v.set(0)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

See more on effbot.org: [Radiobutton](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm)

Comment: just calling stop() function in raised_button function  simple charm have been struggling with , Thanks @furas

Comment: Please i also want to become guru like you guys here in python can you provide any link to website or any resource i can learn to improve my skills.Am open to learning new things .i started by watching videos on youtube and want to improve .

Comment: I use computers almost 30 years so I have learned first language long time ago (before Internet was created) and I don't remeber when  and where I have learned Python. As I know on YouTube very popular is [sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex). See links on [python.zeef.com](https://python.zeef.com/).